How to solve for x in x^2+x=y in assembly 8086?
I'm trying to solve the equation x^2+x=y in assembly 8086, where y is a number I only find once the program runs.
y is the address of another program, which it writes to 0x7511 in the following way:
OR  AL, 0x1
MOV BX, AX
MUL WORD AX
ADD BX, AX
MOV CX, 0x2401
MOV AX, 0x1111
MUL WORD CX
MOV DI, AX
MOV [DI], BX

I tried brute forcing by iteratively running through x until i got the right answer, but that wont work, either because i didnt code it correctly, or the 200k instruction limit runs out.

Compute the integer square root of y e.g. by binary search (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root), i.e. z=floor(sqrt(y)). Then if z*z+z==y you've found your solution and x==z, or the equation has no solution (since z*z<y, but (z+1)*(z+1)=z^2+2z+1>y).

Consider doing same in C or Java first (obviously without using sqrt).  Then when you have it working, take that algorithm to assembly as literally as you can.  This two step approach can quite simplify your assembly programming, as writing an algorithm from scratch in assembly is hard if you don't know the algorithm or assembly language. Using this approach, your assembly questions will be about how to do the same loop or if-then-else statement that you already have working in C, in assembly rather than how to solve some particular math problem in assembly.

Does corewars have an 8087 FPU?  If so, then you have access to fild / fsqrt / fistp.  You could set the FP rounding mode to truncation (toward zero) so the sqrt and the conversion back to integer both use that, and leave it set that way (unlike in normal programs where you want to restore it to the default round-to-nearest for other math ops)
